# Error connection timeout in Xamarin application

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using flurl.http to call an api in xamarin.forms.

```
 async void CallInspectiontype()
        {
            IList<dynamic> list = await "http://192.168.xxx.xx:8085/api/QMSon/GetInsp".GetJsonListAsync();
            var modelList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                modelList.Add(item.Text);
            }
            InspectionTypePicker.ItemsSource = modelList;

        }
```

it was running earlier but not now ! I don't no why that so ?
Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException:  occurred

Comment: I have updated question !

Comment: what exactly is not running? have you debugged the code? where does it breaks?

Comment: if you're getting a timeout there is a typically a connectivity issues between your client and the server

Comment: it runs on laptop but when i call it on mobile connection times out !

Comment: It breaks where api is called !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it's issue I ran visual Studio as Admin and check the internet Connectivity this worked fine for me !